# How to unpublish content when form submitted and notify a user by eMail?

Tags: 7, nodes, forms, rules, flags

In my Drupal 7 site I have content type `Job`.

Recruiters post information about open positions. Registered users can apply for any position by flagging node using the [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) module. I have built custom form for recruiters where they can manage applications. With this form recruiters can review profile and select candidate for position by submitting the form.

I want to hide/unpublish content when form is submitted and notify user via email that his application was confirmed. How can this be done programmatically?

Also I'm using [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules). If these actions can be implemented via `Rules`, how can I create event and conditions to perform actions against specific `user id` and `node id`?

Answer (score 1):

The [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module is, for sure, your best bet for addrerssing this (therefor +1 for this question already ...).

Can you further enhance (edit) your question to explain what you have tried already using Rules? And what worked, or failed, and what the remaining questions are while using the Rules module? I.e.:

- which events?
- which conditions?
- which actions?

For anybody not familiar (enough/yet) with [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules), checkout the 32 (!!!) great, and free, video tutorials [Learn the Rules framework](http://www.wunderkraut.com/content/learn-the-rules-framework), organized in 7 chapters. Possibly also the similar [set of 8 video tutorials](http://www.wunderkraut.com/content/learn-flag-with-nodeone) about the [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) module, often considered as a natural complement to the Rules module.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep it within your custom form, you can modify the `hook_form_submit()` to include a call to [drupal_mail()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!mail.inc/function/drupal_mail/7) to send the message, and then the content un-publishing really depends on what content you want to effect.

I haven't used it before, but you could also take a look at [Rules Forms Support](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_forms) if you want to keep it in Rules:

> Rules Forms Support provides a Rules based method for controlling
>   forms and their elements. The module can be used to alter any form
>   provided by Drupal core or contributed modules. Change element titles,
>   descriptions, weights, and more, or validate form data and set form
>   errors. Rules forms saves time and cost by affording site builders the
>   ability to monitor and alter forms without the need to implement a
>   custom module.